# Python input string error (don't want to use raw_input)

Tags: python

I have a menu that asks for the user to pick one of the options. Since this menu is from 1 to 10, I'm using input besides raw_input.

My code as an if statement that if the number the user inputs is from 1 to 10 it does the option. If the user inputs any number besides that ones, the else statement says to the user pick a number from 1 to 10.

The problem is if the user types an string, lets say for example qwert. It gives me an error because its an string. I understand why and I don want to use raw_input.

What can I do to wen the user types a string it goes to my else statement and print for example "Only numbers are valid. Pick a number from 1 to 10"

I don't want to use any advanced programing to do this

Regards,

Favolas

**EDIT**
Thanks for all your answers and sorry for the late response but I had some health problems.

I couldn't use try or except because my teacher didn't allow it. 
In the end, I've used raw_input because it was the simplest alternative but was glad to see that are many ways to solve this problem.

Regards,

Favolas

Comment: have you tried **try**, **except** statements?

Comment: I would dare say that try,except is not advanced programming, and is really the only logical choice if you don't want to have to test for all possible types of input and to handle them individually.

Comment: -1 This stopped being a valid question when you said you didn't want to use `try... except` blocks. That's like asking how to print the numbers from one to ten without using a loop. The _point_ of exception handling is to give the programmer the ability to, well, _handle exceptions_. What do you have against them?

Comment: @katrielalex: I'm afraid I have disagree with about whether this is a valid question -- as I do with the analogy you used about printing the numbers from 1-10 without a loop -- because both *are* possible, although it's hard to imagine a reason **why** anyone would want to do it that way except perhaps in some special context such as a `lambda` or generator expression.

Comment: If you do not want to use `raw_input` (Python 2.x) or `input` (Python 3.x) and if you do not want to use `try / except` clauses, you might want to check my second answer. Instead of raising exceptions, `None` is returned from special functions when they detect an error.

Comment: @Favolas: **Why** exactly don't you want to use try or except? Maybe that's an unnecessary restriction which actually makes this a much harder problem and/or means it will require a lot more code to solve.

Comment: -1 @favolas: using try/except is not much of **advanced programing** as you have stated in the question, if this is what "restricting" you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can throw an exception when you try to convert your string into a number.
Example:

```
try:
   int(myres)
except:
   print "Only numbers are valid"
```

Answer (score 4):

Im not sure what you consider advanced - a simple way to do it would be with something like this.

```
def getUserInput():
    while True:
        a = raw_input("Enter a number between 1 and 10: ")
        try:
            number = int(a)
            if (0 < number <= 10):
                return number
            else:
                print "Between 1 and 10 please"
        except:
            print "Im sorry, please enter a number between 1 and 10"
```

Here, I have used try/except statements, to ensure that the entered string can be converted to an integer. And a loop (which will keep running) until the entered number is between 1 and 10 (0< number <=10)

Comment: thanks for the answer but I don't want to use try or except

Answer (score 4):

You *should* use `raw_input()`, even if you don't want to :)  This will always give you a string.  You can then use code like

```
s = raw_input()
try:
    choice = int(s)
except ValueError:
    #  choice is invalid...
```

to try to convert to an int.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I don't want to use try or except

Answer (score 3):

What you really are after is how to figure out if something could pass as an integer. The following would do the job:

```
try:
    i = int(string_from_input)
ecxept ValueError:
    # actions in case the input is anything other than int, like continuing the loop
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I don't want to use try or except

Comment: Are you sure? It is the best solution. Another option would be to use the 'isdigit()' function on string objects. If the string contains only digits, ie. no ',' or '.' it will return true.

Answer (score 2):

You clearly have something against exception handling. I don't understand why -- it's a fundamental part of (not just Python) programming and something you should be comfortable with. It's no more 'advanced' than handling error codes, just a different mentality.

Here are the docs. It's pretty simple:

> It is possible to write programs that
>   handle selected exceptions. Look at
>   the following example, which asks the
>   user for input until a valid integer
>   has been entered, but allows the user
>   to interrupt the program (using
>   Control-C or whatever the operating
>   system supports); note that a
>   user-generated interruption is
>   signalled by raising the
>   KeyboardInterrupt exception.
>
> ```
> >>> while True:
> ...     try:
> ...         x = int(raw_input("Please enter a number: "))
> ...         break
> ...     except ValueError:
> ...         print "Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again..."
> ...
> ```
>
> The try statement works as follows.
>
> First, the try clause (the
>   statement(s) between the try and
>   except keywords) is executed. If no
>   exception occurs, the except clause is
>   skipped and execution of the try
>   statement is finished. If an exception
>   occurs during execution of the try
>   clause, the rest of the clause is
>   skipped. Then if its type matches the
>   exception named after the except
>   keyword, the except clause is
>   executed, and then execution continues
>   after the try statement. If an
>   exception occurs which does not match
>   the exception named in the except
>   clause, it is passed on to outer try
>   statements; if no handler is found, it
>   is an unhandled exception and
>   execution stops with a message as
>   shown above. A try statement may have
>   more than one except clause, to
>   specify handlers for different
>   exceptions. At most one handler will
>   be executed. Handlers only handle
>   exceptions that occur in the
>   corresponding try clause, not in other
>   handlers of the same try statement. An
>   except clause may name multiple
>   exceptions as a parenthesized tuple,
>   for example:
>
> ```
> ... except (RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError):
> ...     pass
> ```
>
> The last except clause may omit the
>   exception name(s), to serve as a
>   wildcard. Use this with extreme
>   caution, since it is easy to mask a
>   real programming error in this way! It
>   can also be used to print an error
>   message and then re-raise the
>   exception (allowing a caller to handle
>   the exception as well):

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I liked my first answer better. However, this one should fit your requirements with more code.

```
import sys

def get_number(a, z):
    if a > z:
        a, z = z, a
    while True:
        line = get_line('Please enter a number: ')
        if line is None:
            sys.exit()
        if line:
            number = str_to_int(line)
            if number is None:
                print('You must enter base 10 digits.')
            elif a <= number <= z:
                return number
            else:
                print('Your number must be in this range:', a, '-', z)
        else:
            print('You must enter a number.')

def get_line(prompt):
    sys.stdout.write(prompt)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if line:
        return line[:-1]

def str_to_int(string):
    zero = ord('0')
    integer = 0
    for character in string:
        if '0' <= character <= '9':
            integer *= 10
            integer += ord(character) - zero
        else:
            return
    return integer
```

Comment: Do you need this code converted into one function or so that it does not use any functions?

Answer (score 0):

May I recommend using this function in Python 3.1? The two arguments are the expected number range.

```
def get_number(a, z):
    if a > z:
        a, z = z, a
    while True:
        try:
            line = input('Please enter a number: ')
        except EOFError:
            raise SystemExit()
        else:
            if line:
                try:
                    number = int(line)
                    assert a <= number <= z
                except ValueError:
                    print('You must enter base 10 digits.')
                except AssertionError:
                    print('Your number must be in this range:', a, '-', z)
                else:
                    return number
            else:
                print('You must enter a number.')
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I don't want to use try or except

Comment: @favolas: why this random requirement? what's wrong with try-except?